# Equation involving an integral depending on two parameters

Tags: definite-integrals, transcendental-equations

I have some difficulty to find possible solutions of the following equation:
$$\int_0^\tau dx \frac{1}{x^\alpha+1}=\beta$$
where $\tau \gt 0,$ $\alpha\in \mathbb N$ ($\alpha=1,2,3,\dots$) and $\beta$ a given real valued constant.

Is it possible to find values of $\alpha$ and $\tau$ satisfiyng the equation?

Thanks

Comment: It is possible at least (i) for $\alpha=1$: you get $\log(\tau+1)=\beta$, (ii) for $\alpha=2$: you get $\tan^{-1}(\tau)=\beta$. Maybe you can extend this for composite $\alpha$... specially when $\alpha=2^n$...

Comment: use Partial fraction expansion of $1/(x^4+1)$ and then integrate the parts like [here](http://tinyurl.com/cj9qhzs)

Comment: [W|A](http://tinyurl.com/bts5wqu) says that $\int \frac1{x^\alpha+1}dx=\; _2F_1(1,\frac1n; 1+\frac1n, -x^n) +const$. I don't think that there is an analytical solution. Seems like all you can do is use did's proof of existence and numerics. Happy number crunching!

Comment: @draks:  I believe there is an analytical solution.  Consider multiplying both the numerator and denominator by $x$ to get $\int {\frac{x}{x+x^{\alpha+1}}}$.  Then use partial fractions to get this in terms of $\int {\frac{1}{x+x^{\alpha+1}}}$.  Use the question posed here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172124/  This is a shortcut to evaluate the integrals.  You will also use the property of $\log{ab} = \log{a} + \log{b}$.  I'm working on posting this as an answer...

Comment: @MattGroff I've seen that question too and am looking forward to your answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For every $\alpha$ in $[0,1]$, the function $g_\alpha:\tau\mapsto\int\limits_0^\tau\frac{\mathrm dx}{1+x^\alpha}$ is increasing from $g_\alpha(0)=0$ to $\lim\limits_{\tau\to+\infty}g_\alpha(\tau)=+\infty$. Hence, for each $\beta\geqslant0$, there exists a unique $\tau$ such that $g_\alpha(\tau)=\beta$.

If $\alpha\gt1$, the same result holds provided $\beta\lt\ell_\alpha$, where $\ell_\alpha=\lim\limits_{\tau\to+\infty}g_\alpha(\tau)$ is finite.

Answer (score 0):

We start with:
$$\int_0^\tau {\frac{1}{1+x^\alpha} dx}=\beta$$
$$\int_0^\tau {\frac{x}{x+x^{\alpha+1}} dx}$$

Now consider the following substitution...  Let
$$u=x, \qquad dv=\frac{1}{x+x^{\alpha+1}}dx$$
$$du=dx, \qquad v=\int{\frac{1}{x+x^{\alpha+1}}}dx$$

We get
$$\int {\frac{x}{x+x^{\alpha+1}} dx} = x \int{\frac{1}{x+x^{\alpha+1}}}dx - \int {\left( \int{\frac{1}{x+x^{\alpha+1}} dx }\right) dx}$$

We can then use the shortcut substitution found in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172124/evaluating-int-frac1x10-xdx).  Noting
$$\int { \frac{1}{x + x^\gamma} dx}=\int {\left( \frac{x^{\gamma-1}+1}{x + x^\gamma } - \frac{x^{\gamma-1}}{x + x^\gamma } \right) dx}=f_\gamma(x)$$
$$=\frac{\gamma \log(x) - \log(x + x^\gamma)}{\gamma - 1} = g_\gamma(x)$$

...we can set $\gamma = \alpha + 1$ and our previous equation becomes

$$\int {\frac{x}{x+x^{\alpha+1}} dx} = x \int{\frac{1}{x+x^{\alpha+1}}}dx - \int {\left( \int{\frac{1}{x+x^{\alpha+1}} dx }\right) dx}$$
$$= x g_\gamma(x) - \int { \int{\frac{1}{x+x^{\gamma}} dx } dx}$$

We can now make use of the [Fractional Calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus), or more exactly, the well known [Cauchy formula for repeated integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_formula_for_repeated_integration) to simplify the double integral on the righthand side.  The general formula is:
$$(J^n h)(x) = \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \int_0^x{(x-t)^{n-1} h(t) dt}$$

...where $(J^n h)(x)$ denotes $n$ repeated integrations on the integral of $h(x)$.  Plugging in $\frac{1}{t+t^{\gamma}}$ for $h(t)$, we get

$$\int_0^x {(x-t) \frac{1}{t+t^{\gamma}} dt}$$

**I'll do more work, but I'm stopping for lunch for now...**

Comment: @Riccardo.Alestra:Thanks for a very excellent question that was fun to try to answer.

Comment: @draks: Let me know if you'd like to see more.  I can always post as a seperate question,answer,etc...

Comment: You are making circles: in the last displayed integral, the $x$ part of the parenthesis $(x-t)$ is $xg_\gamma(x)$ and the $t$ part is the integral $I$ you are trying to compute. And indeed $I=xg_\gamma(x)-(xg_\gamma(x)-I)$... Sorry about that.